# How can I add the value if there are duplicate record in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried other solutions but still have no luck, My problem is that I have a list of dictionaries in which I have to check if there are any duplicate value in the key (name of the person):

Sample list:

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "jack","count": 7},{"id": 12,"name": "jack","count": 5}]
```

If there are duplicate names, It should add the value in the key count, and the result should be:

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "jack","count": 12}]
```

Edited: ID's don't matter, I need at least one id to appear.

Comment: why the `id` should be `1`?

Comment: will there be only 2 duplicate values or there can be more

Comment: Sorry about that @BearBrown but the ids don't matter. I need at least one id to appear.

Comment: Unfortunately, there could be more than 2 duplicate @TalhaIsrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detailed solution could be that:

```
new = {}

for d in data:
    name = d["name"]
    if name in new:
        new[name]["count"] += d["count"]
    else:
        new[name] = dict(d)

result = list(new.values())
```

> NB: this could be simplified with the use of [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and the method [get](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm), but I think this one is the more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As `id` field is not so important I will create a `dict` with key as `name` and value being the item values in a list

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = [{"id": 1,"name": "jack","count": 7},{"id": 12,"name": "jack","count": 5}]
d = defaultdict(list)
```

Iterate over the list and map key and values

```
for idx,i in enumerate(a):
    d[i['name']].append(i) #key is 'name'
```

At this point `d` will look like this

> {'jack': [{'count': 7, 'id': 1, 'name': 'jack'},{'count': 5, 'id': 12,
>   'name': 'jack'}]}

Now if the length of list is `>1` means we have to iterate over the `list` and do the summation and update the count

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        temp = v[0]
        for t in v[1:]:
            temp['count'] = temp['count']+t['count'] #update the count
        d[k] = temp
print(list(d.values())) #[{'count': 12, 'id': 1, 'name': 'jack'}]
```

In order to handle the case when `count` is missing like

`[{"id": 1,"name": "jack"},{"id": 12,"name": "jack","count": 5}]`

replace above count update logic with

`temp['count']=temp.get('count',0)+t.get('count',0)`